# Converting byte array to true/false

Tags: powershell

Through various different posts on StackOverflow and other places I was able to put together a powershell script that FTP uploads files and it works great.  However I wanted to add a bit more verbosity to it. See code below:

```
foreach ($file in $uploadfiles)
{

# create the full path to the file on remote server (odd but okay!)
$ftp_command = $ftp + $file

# for debugging
#$ftp_command

# create a new URI object for the full path of the file
$uri = New-Object System.URI($ftp_command)

#for debugging
#$uri

# finally do our upload to the remote server - URI object, full path to local file
#$responseArray = $ftpclient.UploadFile($uri,$file.Fullname)



$result = $ftpclient.UploadFile($uri,$file.Fullname)




if ($result) {
    $file.Fullname + " uploaded successfully"
} else {
    $file.Fullname + " not uploaded successfully"
}

}
```

Basically after the file is uploaded I wanted to check and see if it was successful or not.  Upload file is supposed to return a byte array ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.80).aspx ; *A Byte array containing the body of the response from the resource.*).  I'm new to powershell so that's probably where my problem is, but for the life of me I can't get anything to come out of $result so I can test.  Is it possible the server isn't returning anything or I'm just not accessing/setting the the byte array correctly? I've tried a variety of different things, but haven't yet figured anything out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use the $result in your case begining PowerShell 2.0 you can use the try/catch sections.

```
try
{
  $ftpclient.UploadFile($uri,$file.Fullname)
}
catch [System.Net.WebException]
{
 # here $_ gives you the exception details
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think that will get me where I need to be!